# intellij idea. what library uses project?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, libraries

I have Android Maven project which works with Netbeans and Eclipse and compiles in command line itself, but i have some problems with **Intellij Idea**. After importing the project the IDE complains about non-existing method of imports:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Node; 
cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getTextContent()
```

The method `getTextContent()` added in java version 1.5. I do use 1.7 Oracles JDK. Build target in `pom.xml` points to 1.5

Similar post about problem in Eclipse mentioned [here](http://tinyurl.com/d73hzub) says: 
There are many jars packaged with xml-apis and they sometimes contain the same library routines, but at different versions.

I have searched how to lookup which version of library is used with IDE and how to priorities the right libraries.

Do someone have the answer?

Answer (score 1):

In intellij go to module settings (right click module and its in the context menu).

Select project, you can choose and/or add a project SDK here, If you are using 1.7 it will probably be that version.

when you make/compile your project its probably running against the version above.

You can run maven targets (in my version there is a tab on the right) you should be able to do this if you right click on the pom file, this should compile.

In conclusion
use the same java version on your pom and in your project

Answer (score 1):

try to move Android SDK module up. in "Project structure" -> "Modules" -> "Dependencies". And make sure You do not have the old maven module xml-apis there.